# How to apply styles to multiple components using styled components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, styled-components

I've created a icon.js file. It exports 3 SVG components to different files.
Like this :

```js
export const MenuIcon = () => {
  return (
    <svg>
      ...
    </svg>
  );
};

export const ArrowLeftIcon = () => {
  return (
    <svg>
   ...
    </svg>
  );
};

export const SearchIcon = () => {
  return (
    <svg>
      ...
    </svg>
  );
};
```

And I would like to apply the same styles to all three of these components using styled components, not giving them a same className. Is there a solution for that? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following steps could help you.

### Steps

1. npm i styled-components@4.1.3
2. import styled from 'styled-components';
3. 

```js
const StyledSvg = styled.svg` <---the html tag that you want to style
  color: palevioletred;       <---the css styles that you want to use
`;
```

4. Now use StyledSvg that you just created instead of the svg tags.

   ```js
   return(
       <StyledSvg>
       ...
       </StyledSvg>
   );
   ```